# Drawing inclined lines at any angle

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm trying to draw angles on a bitmap. The problem is, a pixel only has neighbours in 8 directions, so by drawing pixel by pixel, we can only draw lines inclined at 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315 and 360 degrees.

So, how do I draw lines at other inclinations - e.g. 35 or 65 degrees? Like here (a 90x90 bitmap):

[image: Look here at Angles Image]

Are there any limitations - like the minimum canvas size? I'm supposed to be able to do this in a 30 x 30 image.

Comment: what about looking at some trigonometry?

Comment: Question is simple I want to draw Above Image on my C# Picture Box , How to Draw , straight line from a particular (x,y location).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the start and the end point for the line, and let c# do the rest (if you want to do it yourself, you can search [Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)).
So, if you want to build a line with x degrees, you can do the following:

1. Start in the point (0,30).
2. If your angle is less than 45, your ending point should be [30, 30*(1-tan(angle))].
3. If not, its [30*tan(90-angle),0].

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int angle;
    public Form1(int angle)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.angle = angle;   
    }

    private Point EndPoint(int angle)
    {
        var endPoint = new Point();
        if (angle <= 45)
        {
            endPoint.X = 30;
            endPoint.Y = (int) (30 - 30*Math.Tan(Radian(angle)));
        }
        else
        {
            endPoint.Y = 0;
            endPoint.X = (int) (30*Math.Tan(Radian(90-angle)));
        }
        return endPoint;
    }

    private double Radian(int angle) { return (Math.PI/180.0)*angle; }

    public void Draw()
    {
        var myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        var endPoint = EndPoint(angle);
        var formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 30, endPoint.X, endPoint.Y);
        myPen.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();
    }

}
```